# Swift iOS how to convert bytes to Image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, postgresql, graphql

I'm trying to retrieve and visualize an image from postgres to iOS, and I tried turning into Data and then UIImage but with no luck, when i create the UIImage it returns nil.
As you can see from the image below, I get that string from the db, with double backslash and x, that should be normal, I tried both to keep the escaping symbols and to trim them, I also tried to initialize the Data with both initializer with byte: and base64Encoded, with and without options but the image is always nil.
[screenshot from xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyJSW.png)

```
func dataToImage(data:String)->Image{
    var imageData = Data(bytes: "68747470733a2f2f73332e65752d63656e7472616c2d312e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f696c6172696f73616c6174696e6f2f31423236303332462d363935422d344342432d393733412d3342413936343841334535372d373136312d303030303145323833464643303541442e6a706567", count: data.count)
    var base64data = Data(base64Encoded: "68747470733a2f2f73332e65752d63656e7472616c2d312e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f696c6172696f73616c6174696e6f2f31423236303332462d363935422d344342432d393733412d3342413936343841334535372d373136312d303030303145323833464643303541442e6a706567", options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
    return Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: imageData)!)
}
```

the string I get from the db:

```
data    String  "\\x68747470733a2f2f73332e65752d63656e7472616c2d312e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f696c6172696f73616c6174696e6f2f31423236303332462d363935422d344342432d393733412d3342413936343841334535372d373136312d303030303145323833464643303541442e6a706567"
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The String you _get from the db_ looks like a PostgreSQL's native hex format, not base64. You may need to **convert the binary data into base64 on your db side**. And use `Data(base64Encoded:)` on your Swift side.

Comment: Hi, it's not very clear from the snippet but i tried that as well as you can see from the base64data variable, i tried also initializing the uiimage with that and still returns nil

Comment: You are not showing any code on your db side. So, I cannot say anything if you have done it correctly. Maybe I need to repeat again _You may need to convert the binary data into base64 on your db side_ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not saving image data correctly =/

To get UIImage Data properly you should:

```
let data = yourImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
```

It will return an **Data**

So, save it like a String and its ready!

To set image from Data its like these:

```
let data = Data(base64Encoded: myString)
let newImage = UIImage(data: data)
```

To debug more easily use this string to convert to Data and Image. This string provides us a Data and an Image properly

```
"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"
```

I hope it helped you! 
Cheers

Comment: that's the opposite i need to do, i have the byte array string and i need to convert that into an image. That's the string i get from the database where i uploaded the image before.

Comment: Thats the point! Your byte array is wrong! If you use that byte what I provide this gonna work!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class ImageConverter {

    func base64ToImage(_ base64String: String) -> UIImage? {
        guard let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) else { return nil }
        return UIImage(data: imageData)
    }

    func imageToBase64(_ image: UIImage) -> String? {
        return image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.base64EncodedString()
    }

}
```

Comment: i tried that as well, sorry but it's not clear from my snippet, it always returns nil, both with base64 string or byte